# Best way to use third-party APIs with many domains

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, caching

We have a product as a service that we sell on our domain, and we sell it to other people to resell on their own domain. (We also have a system with has a ton of domains built into it, with more added relatively regularly)

Most third-party APIs seem to require "authorized urls" that can grab the data. This is getting more and more impossible, especially as some programming interfaces have a limit of 5 or 10 or so domains per account.

Is there any **good** way to get API data on an ever growing list of domain names? I thought about caching data on a `xhynk.com/DOMAIN`, and just adding "xhynk.com" to each API, but I feel like that isn't the best way to go.

Do I have any other options?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Why is it getting more and more impossible? It seems to me that you should just have one Apache vhost with as many aliases as have you have resellers. What is the 5-10 domains/account restriction about?

Comment: Let's say I want to create a facebook app for the system. It allows me to have only a few domains attached to it. So if I have 100 different domains, I need to create a new app every few domains.

Comment: Why do you need to "create an app every few domains"? Why not create one app that covers all your users/resellers, and just alias all the domains to one vhost? You can do the internal logic to detect which reseller they are inside your app.

Comment: "It allows me to have only a few domains attached to it" - what is "it" here - Facebook? (The confusion here is, I think, whether you mean the domain restriction is on your server or on remote APIs generally, such as Facebook).

Comment: They require separate installations of the software. We can't just show the system on "mysite.com" and have Joe sign in to "joesite.com" aliased to (or parked on) mysite.com.

Comment: Actually, unless I have misunderstood your situation, aliasing multiple domains to one installation of your API system is exactly what you should do. In your API logic you can connect to a different database (if necessary, though not recommended - one database is probably enough). If you use one database you can also filter by the domain in use - all the environmental information you need is in `$_SERVER`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but since you posted it under PHP, you might create in another language the code you need as an executable. Then simply run that file and redirects its output (if you need to).

Notice though the permissions of the account that is running PHP. For coding you could use C++ or C# (Mono if you're on Linux), Basic or whatever language that can create an executable. You might feel less restricted in other languages.

You're probably not on Windows, but since I am:

```
<?php
 $FileList=`dir c:\*.* /w`; // A windows or a UNIX command; notice marks direction
  print "<br> $FileList <br>";
?>
```

For Windows one could create something something that Windows can execute and place it in the same location as dir.exe; there are other constructions possible but I just keep this simple.

You might dive into PHP in combo with Python, Perl or Ruby, to extend coding possibilities on the server. As for JavaScript it's client-side code and usually the limit for client server interaction (timing out etc). Server-side code runs also on different permissions as client side code. So more thing might be possible then.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is an answer to the question. I appreciate the question isn't very clear, but I think the OP is looking for an architectural approach to running their API on many domains (and possibly about permitting other domains to access them too, maybe by referrer - not sure). I don't think switching languages is going to help.

Comment: probably his client side approach times out (things getting to large he wrote), some c++ / c# code, could be complexer and quicker to run then javascript (under which he posted this too). You're probably right he's hitting some design limit. (but he's in that situation, and probaply cannt change that)
In for example c# or c++ one could launch something complex over multi tasked threats, and return an answer fast. I dont think php could do that. But as for sample i tried to keep it simple as possible with a little bit out of the box thinking and so I used executable example Dir C:\*.* /w

Comment: Ah, you're talking about background tasks. Yes, PHP can do that; however, I am not sure that's the issue the OP is asking about. I think this is essentially a Apache/vhost problem, but the OP isn't aware that one API application can service as many domains as required, whilst appearing to various callers as several isolated systems.

Comment: I'm not hosting APIs, I have a sole API that works pretty well. I'm trying to include OTHER API's (Google's, Facebooks, Vendasta, R.C.C, etc.) into my system. THOSE systems limit me to ~5-10 domains per account (namely FB). I need my hundreds of domains to be able to drag info from their API's without creating an account for **every** domain.

Comment: Not necessarily just "drag info from", they need to be able to interact with them.

Comment: @Xhynk: "I'm not hosting APIs, I have a sole API that works pretty well" appears to be self-contradictory. Either you are, or you are not, hosting an API.

Comment: @Xhynk: "I'm trying to include OTHER API's (Google's, Facebooks, Vendasta, R.C.C, etc.) into my system". Can you edit into your question more about this? If you are doing this from your one API, on the server, on behalf of your various customers, you can make do with one Facebook API account, right? Is the problem related to your customers wishing to make calls directly to Facebook on the client in JavaScript? That would expose their domain to Facebook and not yours. If not, please try to explain where this limitation comes from.

Comment: Not sure but couldnt you use some kind of pass through authentication. thinking of this, are you writing some kind of snooping fishing tool for facebook i wonder if that would be legal.